# gdb/solaris: When attaching to a process, symbols not being loaded

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb, solaris

I'm using gcc 4.9.2 & gdb 7.2 in Solaris 10 on sparc.  The following was tested after compiling/linking with `-g`, `-ggdb`, and `-ggdb3`.

When I attach to a process:

```
~ gdb
/snip/
(gdb) attach pid_goes_here
```

... it is not loading symbolic information.  I started with netbeans which starts gdb without specifying the executable name until after the attach occurs, but I've eliminated netbeans as the cause.

I can force it to load the symbol table under netbeans if I do one of the following:

Attach to the process, then in the debugger console do one of the following:

```
(gdb) detach
(gdb) file /path/to/file
(gdb) attach the_pid_goes_here
```

or

```
(gdb) file /path/to/file
(gdb) sharedlibrary .
```

I want to know if there's a more automatic way I can force this behavior.  So far googling has turned up zilch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if there's a more automatic way I can force this behavior.

It looks like a bug.

Are you sure that the main executable symbols *are* loaded? [This bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17903) says that `attach pid` without giving the binary doesn't work on Solaris at all.

In any case, it's supposed to work automatically, so your best bet to make it work better is probably to file a bug, and wait for it to be fixed (or send a patch to fix it yourself :-)

Comment: It looks like you're right.  No symbolic information is loaded initially.  I re-did my test from a clean gdb session; if I don't use `file`, or `exec-file / symbol-file` before using `sharedlibrary .` it doesn't load any symbolic information.